# Limiting the number of entries to be added to a Django model with a Foreign Key

Tags: django

I am creating a real estate system using Django. I have Property models where the number of available units is defined.

I have a separate Model for units, where each unit of a property is defines with its unique characteristics.

I want to limit the number of units to be added not to exceed the number of units as defined in the Property Model.

How do I accomplish that.

The Property model is as shown below:

```py
# property
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Property Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(PropertyOwner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(PropertyType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_of_units = models.IntegerField('Number of Units')
    date_added = models.DateField('Date added')
```

The unit model is as defined:

```py
class Unit(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `save` method in `Unit` model to prohibit creating more than N relations:

```py
class Unit(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        max_units = self.property.no_of_units
        if self.property.unit_set.count() > max_units :
            raise Exception(f'Cannot add more than {max_units} relations')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: Didn't notice `no_of_units` field

Comment: the `no_of_units` is as defined in the property class:

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Unit(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        allowed_units = self.property.no_of_units

        if Unit.objects.filter(property=self.property).count() >= allowed_units:
            raise ValidationError('Maximum units limit exceed!')
        super(Unit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thank you it worked, is there a simple way to throw a customized error when a user submits the form after the limit is exceeded